# How to use QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY(mp: QgsMultiPolygon). Error when passing in multipolygon

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to create a `QgsGeometry` object to pass to a feature by using the `fromMultiPolygonXY` method. I have successfully constructed a `QgsMultiPolygon`, but I am getting an error saying `an unexpected type of QgsMultiPolygon`.

```
mp = QgsMultiPolygon()
mp.fromWkt(binary.wkt)
print(mp.geometryType())
geom = feat.geometry()
geom.fromMultiPolygonXY(mp)
```

[image: from the docs]

[image: and my error]

Output in QGIS map

[image: layer added to map]

Answer (score 3):

Use in this way:

```
geom = QgsGeometry().fromWkt(binary.wkt)
feat.setGeometry(geom)
```

Comment: I have actually tried this. I do get something to render, but the geometry is incorrect. Consoling the wkt out: ```MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.678215654852 35.36377406287188, -80.678215654852 35.06308084204256, -80.17009797907075 35.06308084204256, -80.17009797907075 35.36377406287188, -80.678215654852 35.36377406287188)))```. This is the intended wkt. When throwing it in Wicket online, I get the correct rectangle. However, it looks like a polygon crossed over itself in Q. That's when I attempted this other method of explicitly creating a ```QgsMultiPolygon``` to pass to the ```QgsGeometry``` object.

Comment: The multipolygon is not crossing over itself. It is a valid polygon. What I don't understand is why you make a polygon using `QgsMultiPolygon` while `QgsGeometry().fromWkt` can make it?

Comment: I would definitely be using fromWkt, but I'm seeing a sliver in the map viewer instead of the expected rectangle. Sorry, I am very new to Q and developing in Q.

Comment: This multipolygon is a simple rectangle. There is not any sliver.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I'm not seeing a simple rectangle when the geometry is added to the map. Are there other checks I need to perform? Thank you.

Comment: What is coordinate system of project? (displayed bottom right of the QGIS) EPSG:????

Comment: Project is 4326, and just confirmed the layer is also 4326.

Comment: I've no idea. When I use the WKT string above, I get an ordinary rectangle. Are you sure you wrote the correct wkt?

Comment: What version of Q are you using?

Comment: QGIS 3.16.0 Hannover

Comment: I am using the same. Saving layer in spatialite file.

Comment: I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5xtj.png

Comment: Yes, that is what I am hoping to see.

Comment: Try to use QuickWKT pugin to draw the multipolygon. It is easy to use.

Comment: I'm stuck here. I have no idea why this is happening. Sorry.

Comment: I recreated the layer using "project crs: EPSG:4326" instead of "EPSG:4326" and it worked. Would you be able to explain the difference?